# What Issues prevent Java applications from working on multiple platforms?

Tags: java, cross-platform

Java is supposed to be "write once, run anywhere" and it really can be, but in some cases it turns into "write once, debug everywhere".

What are the most common reasons for problems when moving a Java application from one platform to another?

What are un-common but interesting reasons?

Comment: base on the comments its "write once, run anywhere"

Answer (score 31, accepted):

- Don't make assumptions about the case (in)sensitivity of the file system
- Don't make assumptions about the path or directory separator
- Don't make assumptions about the line terminator
- Don't use the default platform encoding unless you're really, really sure you mean to
- Don't start "cmd.exe" etc (I know, it sounds obvious - but I've seen it cause problems)

Comment: Also: Don't make assumption about path prefixes like \\, C:, /

Comment: I like to raise some noise at our office every now and then about hardcoding /dev/null around the app. Yes, it works nicely as long as you're not running Windows which is supposed to be one of the main platforms we support...

Comment: Don't make assumption about readers reading direction rtl ltr ttb

Comment: @jpse: That's not so much a *platform* issue as a *UI* issue which could occur on any platform.

Comment: @jonSkeet Of course it is in most cases a UI thingy. You may expand it on encoding... make sure to use something like utf-8

Answer (score 14):

Few from UI area:

- Incorrect ordering of buttons like OK/Cancel
- Using absolute layouts
- Different accelerator keys
- Different sizes/rendering of fonts
- Expecing certain keys to be present (Windows key, Meta key)

(These are not Java specific though)

Comment: They may not be Java specific, but it's easy to forget those

Answer (score 9):

I can only speak from personal experience.  These are things I've seen:

1. Threading is abstracted differently on some architectures, so there are slight differences in delays and possibly ordering. (Which could lead to some race conditions)
2. Controlling the keyboard's statuses (caps lock, num lock, etc) doesn't always work as expected (Linux didn't allow me to change the caps lock to disabled v1.5 at the time)

Answer (score 7):

Using classes from the `com.sun.*` packages that come with the Sun JDK.

Comment: Why is this an issue?

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you can write to the directory that contains your applications.

Comment: When and why is this an issue?

Answer (score 5):

Using JNI is something that should be looked into. Providing the native library for every target platform can reduce this problem.

Comment: Not if you have libraries for each platform where you want to run your application. At my job I develop an application, which uses external lib via JNI on Windows and Linux. Unfortunately, this library is not available for Mac OS :-(

Comment: But you still limit yourself to all platforms for which you ship the native library instead of all platforms that run Java.

Comment: Yes, that's right. I just wanted to point out that JNI may not necessarily be a problem. (But it is obviously something to check, so +1).

Answer (score 1):

There are many different JVMs, so depending on which one the client has installed on their box, they may get slightly different results.

Comment: Don't they all have to obey an API and contracts?

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head...some of these actually happened at work

- JNI
- Development tool introduced
  characters into formatted string
  literals that worked under Windows
  but didn't work under Linux (this
  actually happened)
- File system inconsistencies (tightly coupling an application to one environment)
- Underlying hardware such as available memory or cores could result in a change of behavior