# Is Java the same in Linux and Windows?

Tags: java, cross-platform

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What Issues prevent Java applications from working on multiple platforms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453538/what-issues-prevent-java-applications-from-working-on-multiple-platforms)

I am starting to learn Java and I am researching if there are significant differences between Java on Linux (Ubuntu) and on Windows?

Thank you!

Comment: Java kinda advertises itself as being cross-platform...

Comment: Kinda depends on your definition of "significant". For most people, the answer is "no differences".

Comment: There will be some difference when you are writing code to deal with default location in the system to store data.

Answer (score 3):

> Write once, run everywhere

This is Java's philosophy. The only thing that differs on different platforms is the JVM which converts Java bytecode to the actual machine code.

Answer (score 2):

Java is the same everywhere : **JVM**.

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2748910/how-is-java-platform-independent-when-it-needs-jvm-to-run) , might help.

Comment: Thanks. I just needed someone to tell me that because as a first time java coder that's one of my hesitations. I've been programming on PHP and Ruby for quite some time and now I want to try mobile programming.

Answer (score 2):

The Java Language specification is the same everywhere. What differs is the JVM implementation which is specific to the platform.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the VM you are using. Depending on it, some things might differ - the size of boolean for instance is dependent on VM. If you use the same VM in both linux and windows, then nothing will differ.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** As its famously know `"WORA"` **(Write Once Run Anywhere)**.

**2.** There will be few **noticeable differences if you use** `AWT` on Window and Linux, as **AWT will use the Peer Components** of the underlying platform, for the look and feel .